# Hera dual monitor HDMI

Tags: release-hera, hdmi

I'm new to EOS.
Installed Hera on Huawei Matebook 14 AMD Ryzen 4800h and everything is ok (wifi included).
Second HP 27 inches display, connected to laptop via HDMI, is not detected.
I' ve searched far and wide on forum and Google, without success.
Please, can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Huawei MateBooks will sometimes not auto-extend a display. That said, you pay be able to trigger the function by pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> (or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>) to trigger the BIOS toggle. Some models may also use <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, matigo, but unfortunately your suggestion doesn't work.
Any other idea?
The fact is that second monitor is not detected in the monitor section of control panel.